# how to render the DATABASE result in a loop , while getting the data from the database is ASYNC task NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, async-await

i am trying to update few fields of a database using a single for loop  ,
and in each loop i am checking if the fields is empty or not if its not empty then update...

inside my root i used this code :

```
for (let i = 0; i < editReqs.length; i++) {
          if (req.body[editReqs[i]]) {
            const SQL = "UPDATE " + dailyReportTable + " SET " + editReqs[i] + " = $1 WHERE id = $2;"
            pool.query(SQL, [req.body[editReqs[i]], req.body.id], function (dbError, dbResult) {
              if (dbError) {
               res.render("dbError")
                callback()
                return
              }
              else{
              console.log(dbResult)
             }
            })
          }
        }
     //sending the res.render("success")
```

but i got this error : ***Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.***

the reason is because i am send a response in every loop and it is not allowed.
so i tryed another way .

```
var err;
for (let i = 0; i < editReqs.length; i++) {
          if (req.body[editReqs[i]]) {
            const SQL = "UPDATE " + dailyReportTable + " SET " + editReqs[i] + " = $1 WHERE id = $2;"
            pool.query(SQL, [req.body[editReqs[i]], req.body.id], function (dbError, dbResult) {
              if (dbError) {
          // save the error 
                err = true
                callback()
                return
              }
            })
          }
        // check is there is an error
        if (err === false) {
          res.redirect("/")
        }
         // redirect with params if an error occured
        else {
          res.redirect("http://nihuleapi.herokuapp.com/? 
         message=an%20error%20occured%20please%20try%20again")
        }
```

the problem is since getting data from the database is **an async task**, the "err variable" is not what i assume it is ....
how could i *wait* for the database task and then assigning the "err variable" and then redirect the the appropriate path?
any idea ?
thanks for your help

Comment: Can `pool.query` be awaited? `await pool.query(...)` would make your life so much simpler

Comment: i already tried it and its did'nt worked for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options

1. Wrap the query in an async function with Promise
   e.x.

   async function update (i, dailyReportTable, editReqs, req ) {

   ```
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

          const SQL = "UPDATE " + dailyReportTable + " SET " + editReqs[i] + " =  $1 WHERE id = $2;"

          pool.query(SQL, [req.body[editReqs[i]], req.body.id], function (dbError, dbResult) {

            if (dbError) {

               reject(dbError)

            }else{

              resolve(dbResult)

            }

          })

       })
   }
   ```

then in the for loop call the function as

```
await update(i, dailyReportTable, editReqs, req);
```

but wrap each call in a try catch block and if you have an error save it in array as global variable declared above the foor loop

```
try{
  await update(i, dailyReportTable, editReqs, req);
}catch(e){
  errors.push(e)
}
```

then if you have errors.length>0 send after the foor loop finish that you have an error
e.x.

```
if(errors.length>0){
   res.render('error')
}else{
   res.render('success')
}
```

2. 2nd option if the sql package you use is mysql2 it has support for promise e.x. mysql2/promise, so the pool can obtain a promise
   e.x.

   var poolPromise = pool.promise();

and call await on the poolPromise as

```
 await poolPromise.query('');
```